# Passing data from one controller to another controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How do I pass data from one controller to another?

I read many things like use root Scope, use services, use broadcast event etc., but nothing seems to be working. Can some one please guide me?

Comment: See this question for a code example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers

Comment: here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/T2QZMamO8tg5wPnm2V40?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **[Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)** or [`factory`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) to share the data across the controllers.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("clientApp", [])
 app.controller("TestCtrl", 
   function($scope,names) {
     $scope.names =[];
    $scope.save= function(){
      names.add($scope.name);
    }
   
   
   }
  );
  
 app.controller("TestCtrl2", 
   function($scope,names) {   
   
   $scope.getnames = function(){
     $scope.names = names.get();
   }
  }
  );
app.factory('names', function(){
  var names = {};

  names.list = [];

  names.add = function(message){
    names.list.push({message});
  };
  
  names.get = function(){
    return names.list;
  };

  return names;
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html >

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="clientApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    <button ng-click="save()" > save</button>
    
  </div>
  
  <div ng-init="getnames()" ng-controller="TestCtrl2">
     <div  ng-repeat="name in names">
       {{name}}
       </div>
     
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[DEMO WITH ROUTE](https://plnkr.co/edit/hWlqRBVgq5Jx3kzFx6Xc?p=preview)

Comment: what did you try with this

Comment: post the plunker link here

Comment: hi sajeetharan, sorry for the late reply but the scenario is i have to take the data from one controller as pass it to the other controller.In your example i only see one controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133309/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-ritesh).

Comment: @ritesh i have updated the answer check with the sample

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you are switching controller due to state change. Then an easy way to pass data from parent controller to any child controller apart from using factory or services is using state params

// In parent controller
$state.go('child.state', {
        'key' : $scope.value
    });
 //In child controller
$scope.sentObject = angular.copy($stateParams.key);
```

Comment: It is not a parent child controller relationship.

Comment: It doesn't have to be, It just sends some value  to angular along with the state your are changing to. And you can access it in the controller of this new state.